# Db2 connection error

Tags: jdbc, db2

im trying to connect my java to db2 database but im getting an error :

"Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error that will affect the successful execution of subsequent DDM commands or SQL statements.
A connection could not be established to the database because manager 0x2407 at level 0x3 is not supported."

What do you think im doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class conUrl {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jdbcClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    String url="jdbc:db2://host:50000/test";
    String user="dbuser";
    String password="passwrod";

    Connection connection = null;
    //Statement st = null;
    //Result rs = null; 


    try {
        //Load class into memory
        Class.forName(jdbcClassName);
        //Establish connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);




    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(connection!=null){
            System.out.println("Connected successfully.");
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

 }

  }
```

Comment: My guess is that your JBDC DB2 driver is too old to access your more up to date DB2 database or your driver is too modern to access your older DB2 database.  What's the version number of your JDBC driver and the version number of the DB2 database you're trying to connect to?

Comment: I guess your right sir, Im using the latest JDBC driver and the DB im using here at school is version 5.2 . Do you have any idea on how can i find the right driver for my db version? Thanks

Comment: That port number is usually used for _local_ DB2 instances - I don't know if 'official' deployments change that.  If it is on your machine, are you able to use a more recent version instead (given that the current free version is 10.1)?

Comment: hello sir. I want to use a recent one but i cant and im not allowed coz we only used the version of 5.2 of the db2.is there anyway i can find a suitable driver on my db2 version?

Comment: any idea sir on where can i get the driver for my version? Thanks

Comment: You are trying to use a JDBC client that is not compatible with your very old database server.  The newest DB2 client you can use with DB2 v5.2 would be a DB2 6.1 client.  If your professor is requiring you to use DB2 v5.2 (which was dropped from support well over 10 years ago – DB2 v7.1 was dropped from support in June, 2002!), then I would suggest you ask your professor to provide the JDBC drivers that were supplied with the database.